# apex report page turning results

Tags: jquery, oracle-apex

I am trying to utilise a page turning jQuery module called jQuery Booklet onto an Apex search report. Shown here: http://builtbywill.com/code/booklet/

My goal is to have one search result row represented on a page.

The Booklet jQuery comes with many js and css files.

Firstly: 
Where can I upload these files through the Apex front end?

Secondly:
How do I reference these files through html?

Thirdly:
How can I integrate Apex items into the HTML?

I understand this is completely newbie, but any sort of advice would be useful.

Cheers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Download Booklet zip file
2. In your Apex Application, go to **Shared Components > Static Files** and upload the following files from the *booklet* subfolder. (I didn't include Jquery file because APEX already has this).

   - jquery.booklet.latest.min.js
   - jquery.easing.1.3.js
   - jquery-ui-1.10.1.custom.min
3. Go to **Shared Components > Cascading Stylesheets** and upload the following:

   - jquery.booklet.latest.css
4. Go back to the relevant apex page. On the left column (**Page Rendering)**, click on the edit button next to the page. If you're on tree view, double click the page to edit it
5. Add the following to the **Javascript > file URLS** textarea.

   ```
   #WORKSPACE_IMAGES#jquery-ui-1.10.1.custom.min.js
   #WORKSPACE_IMAGES#jquery.easing.1.3.js
   #WORKSPACE_IMAGES#jquery.booklet.latest.min.js
   ```

   Add the following line to the **CSS > File URLS**  textarea

   ```
   #WORKSPACE_IMAGES#jquery.booklet.latest.css
   ```

   **Note:** if you have an old version of apex and can't find the above textareas, don't worry, just add the following to **HTML Header**

   ```
   <script src="#WORKSPACE_IMAGES#jquery-ui-1.10.1.custom.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>    
   <script src="#WORKSPACE_IMAGES#jquery.easing.1.3.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
   <script src="#WORKSPACE_IMAGES#jquery.booklet.latest.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
   <link href="#WORKSPACE_IMAGES#jquery.booklet.latest.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen, projection, tv" />
   ```
6. Create a new HTML Region called 'Booklet'. Ensure that **Region Template** is set to 'No Template'. Set the source to the following.

   ```
   <div id="mybook">
       <div> 
           <h3>Yay, Page 1!</h3>
       </div>
       <div> 
           <h3>Yay, Page 2!</h3>
       </div>
       <div> 
           <h3>Yay, Page 3!</h3>
       </div>
       <div> 
           <h3>Yay, Page 4!</h3>
       </div>
   </div>

   <script>

   $(function() {
       //single book
       $('#mybook').booklet();
   });

   </script>
   ```
7. Run the page to test it! If it doesn't work, view source and make sure all the files are linked correctly.
8. Integrate APEX items by using the format `&P1_ITEM.` in the Region Source.
9. To configure the booklet, see http://builtbywill.com/code/booklet/demos/size

   ### EDIT - how to create a basic booklet report template

   Just saw that you want a report, not a plain old HTML region. I still recommend you do above steps to make sure the plugins work. When it's working smoothly, do the following:
10. Go to **Shared components > Templates**. Under the **Reports** subheading, copy the report **One Column Unordered List**. If it doesn't exist, copy any vertical report.
11. In the new report template, enter the following:

    - Before Rows: `<div id="mybook">`
    - Before Each Row: `<div>`
    - Column Template 1: `#COLUMN_VALUE#`
    - After Each Row: `</div>`
    - After Rows:

      ```
      </div>
      <script>

      $(function() {
      //single book
      $('#mybook').booklet();

      });

      </script>
      ```
    - All other fields should be blank.
12. Go to a new Apex page. Create a new report, set the Region template to **No Template** and the Report template to the one you just created.

Comment: To even push this further you could create extra region templates. One for the 'book' region, with the current subregion template, and an template for the page regions. You can then simply create regions and assign items to the regions, which could prevent a good deal of manual coding (depending on what end result you want of course).

Comment: Hey Rohan, thank you for your amazing advice!
Unfortunately the script does not appear to have any output on step 7, I have uploaded the files into static files and css respectively, and I have pasted the script html into the header files as I could not find the file URLs area within the rendering pages. (I'm using Apex 4.1.1.x). I only see a JavaScript "Function and Global Variable Declaration" box, and no CSS options either.

Comment: I tried pasting it in a field called **HTML header**, and works for me. Try viewing source in Firefox/Chrome/Firebug, and clicking on each file to see if link is broken or not.

Comment: I found the problem!

I had to include type="text/javascript" into my booklet calling function!

Comment: I also added the jQuery file into my header, that might have been the real reason!